# MSDTC settings/properties getting reset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, msdtc

Very often we are getting this error in our Production box.

> Error Message: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "......"
>   returned message "No transaction is active."

Each time the problem seems to be somehow MSDTC settings has all been reset. i.e., we find these options unchecked `Network DTC Access`, Allow Inbound`and`Allow Outbound`.

Even if we check those options again, save it, restart the MSDTC Services, SQL Service -- It works only for few days. After that the same issue pops up again. How to find out why is this settings getting unchecked automatically?

Does the way we code matters for this case? Can tempdb pressure or transaction log growth could crash msdtc service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crashing MSDTC wouldn't cause settings to get revoked if they are properly stored.
It's possible that when you change the settings the new configuration isn't being stored correctly or that configuration is being overwritten somehow. 
I would look in the registrey keys when MSDTC is functioning to check the configuration is as you would expect, once the MSDTC issue arises again I would then compare the registry to what was there previously to see if a) the registry is being updated correctly in the first place and b) to see if the registry is being overwritten at some point and reversing the configuration changes.

MyComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC